# Apple Store - What happens to current build when new build is being reviewed?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

This is our first iOS application on the Apple Store and v1.0 has been approved and Ready For Sales.

Now we are updating with new build v1.1 with fixes so anyone knows if current build (v1.0) is still available for testers/users while new build (v1.1) is being reviewed?

Cheers,
H

Comment: Someone mind explain the down vote? I've done some research around and found mixed/old responses that was why I tried asking for latest info. Like I said, this one said all your builds would be down [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611559/apple-testflight-keep-build-available-while-new-one-is-in-review)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, v1.0 is still available. There is an option to hold the build until you want it to release. Else until the new build gets updated in all apple servers, your users will still see the v1.0. Normally it takes sometime, for all the users to receive the latest version depending on their location.

Answer (score 2):

Your current version is available until you release the new version to the store for sale.  You can check the "automatically release new versions" checkbox and as soon as the review passes it will release.